# Simple Injector and SolrNet

Tags: c#, solrnet, simple-injector

I'm moving from the easy world of Ninject over to the fast world of Simple Injector, but I'm getting stuck with SolrNet. A lot of the popular IoC's have SolrNet integrations already, but not SimpleInjector.

I've started creating my own integration by converting the Unity stuff found at
https://github.com/mausch/SolrNet/tree/master/Unity.SolrNetIntegration

Does anyone either know if this has been done before ( by someone with better knowledge than me) or can anyone convert the below to use simple injector:

```
private static void RegisterSolrOperations(SolrCore core, IUnityContainer container, bool isNamed = true) {
        var ISolrReadOnlyOperations = typeof (ISolrReadOnlyOperations<>).MakeGenericType(core.DocumentType);
        var ISolrBasicOperations = typeof (ISolrBasicOperations<>).MakeGenericType(core.DocumentType);
        var ISolrOperations = typeof (ISolrOperations<>).MakeGenericType(core.DocumentType);
        var SolrServer = typeof (SolrServer<>).MakeGenericType(core.DocumentType);
        var registrationId = isNamed ? core.Id : null;
        var injectionConstructor = new InjectionConstructor(
            new ResolvedParameter(ISolrBasicOperations, registrationId),
            new ResolvedParameter(typeof (IReadOnlyMappingManager)),
            new ResolvedParameter(typeof (IMappingValidator)));
        container.RegisterType(ISolrOperations, SolrServer, registrationId, injectionConstructor);
        container.RegisterType(ISolrReadOnlyOperations, SolrServer, registrationId, injectionConstructor);
    }
```

So far I have:

```
private static void RegisterSolrOperations(SolrCore core, Container container, bool isNamed = true)
    {
        var ISolrReadOnlyOperations = typeof(ISolrReadOnlyOperations<>).MakeGenericType(core.DocumentType);
        var ISolrBasicOperations = typeof(ISolrBasicOperations<>).MakeGenericType(core.DocumentType);
        var ISolrOperations = typeof(ISolrOperations<>).MakeGenericType(core.DocumentType);
        var SolrServer = typeof(SolrServer<>).MakeGenericType(core.DocumentType);
        var registrationId = isNamed ? core.Id : null;

        var injectionConstructor = new InjectionConstructor(
            new ResolvedParameter(ISolrBasicOperations, registrationId),
            new ResolvedParameter(typeof(IReadOnlyMappingManager)),
            new ResolvedParameter(typeof(IMappingValidator)));

        container.Register(ISolrOperations, SolrServer, registrationId, injectionConstructor);
        container.Register(ISolrReadOnlyOperations, SolrServer, registrationId, injectionConstructor);            
    }
```

But the injectionConstructor lines are obviously not for simple injector.

Thanks

**UPDATE**
I should have mention that I was using solrNet 0.4.x so config will be slightly different.
After looking at Steven's answer I now have:

```
container.RegisterSingle<IReadOnlyMappingManager>(
                new MemoizingMappingManager(new AttributesMappingManager()));

container.Register<ISolrDocumentPropertyVisitor, DefaultDocumentVisitor>();
container.Register<ISolrFieldParser, DefaultFieldParser>();
container.RegisterAllOpenGeneric(typeof(ISolrDocumentActivator<>), typeof(SolrDocumentActivator<>));
container.RegisterAllOpenGeneric(typeof(ISolrDocumentResponseParser<>), typeof(SolrDocumentResponseParser<>));
container.Register<ISolrFieldSerializer, DefaultFieldSerializer>();
container.Register<ISolrQuerySerializer, DefaultQuerySerializer>();
container.Register<ISolrFacetQuerySerializer, DefaultFacetQuerySerializer>();

container.RegisterAllOpenGeneric(typeof(ISolrAbstractResponseParser<>), typeof(DefaultResponseParser<>));
container.Register<ISolrHeaderResponseParser, HeaderResponseParser<string>>();
container.Register<ISolrExtractResponseParser, ExtractResponseParser>();

container.RegisterAll<IValidationRule>(new[] { 
    typeof(MappedPropertiesIsInSolrSchemaRule), 
    typeof(RequiredFieldsAreMappedRule), 
    typeof(UniqueKeyMatchesMappingRule)
});

container.Register<ISolrConnection>(() => new SolrConnection(url));
container.RegisterAllOpenGeneric(typeof(ISolrMoreLikeThisHandlerQueryResultsParser<>), typeof(SolrMoreLikeThisHandlerQueryResultsParser<>));
container.RegisterAllOpenGeneric(typeof(ISolrQueryExecuter<>), typeof(SolrQueryExecuter<>));
container.RegisterAllOpenGeneric(typeof(ISolrDocumentSerializer<>), typeof(SolrDocumentSerializer<>));
container.RegisterAllOpenGeneric(typeof(ISolrBasicOperations<>), typeof(SolrBasicServer<>));
container.RegisterAllOpenGeneric(typeof(ISolrBasicReadOnlyOperations<>), typeof(SolrBasicServer<>));
container.RegisterAllOpenGeneric(typeof(ISolrOperations<>), typeof(SolrServer<>));
container.RegisterAllOpenGeneric(typeof(ISolrReadOnlyOperations<>), typeof(SolrServer<>));
container.Register<ISolrSchemaParser, SolrSchemaParser>();
container.Register<ISolrDIHStatusParser, SolrDIHStatusParser>();
container.Register<IMappingValidator, MappingValidator>();
```

but with this I get the error:

> The constructor of the type MappingValidator contains the parameter of
>   type IValidationRule[] with name 'rules' that is not registered.
>   Please ensure IValidationRule[] is registered in the container, or
>   change the constructor of MappingValidator.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That Unity configuration looks overly complex, the Ninject configuration is much simpler. I'm not sure why that Unity configuration is that complex.

I grabbed the Ninject configuration and translated to Simple Injector. Since I'm not familiar with Solr, it could be that Solr depends a few extra tweaks in the Simple Injector configuration, but I think this will get you going:

```cs
// using SimpleInjector;

public static void Configure(Container container, string serverURL)
{
    container.RegisterInstance<IReadOnlyMappingManager>(
        new MemoizingMappingManager(new AttributesMappingManager()));
    container.Register<ISolrDocumentPropertyVisitor, DefaultDocumentVisitor>();
    container.Register<ISolrFieldParser, DefaultFieldParser>();
    container.Register(typeof(ISolrDocumentActivator<>), typeof(SolrDocumentActivator<>));
    container.Register(typeof(ISolrDocumentResponseParser<>), typeof(SolrDocumentResponseParser<>));
    container.Register<ISolrFieldSerializer, DefaultFieldSerializer>();
    container.Register<ISolrQuerySerializer, DefaultQuerySerializer>();
    container.Register<ISolrFacetQuerySerializer, DefaultFacetQuerySerializer>();

    container.Collection.Register(typeof(ISolrResponseParser<>), new[] { 
        typeof(ResultsResponseParser<>), 
        typeof(HeaderResponseParser<>), 
        typeof(FacetsResponseParser<>), 
        typeof(HighlightingResponseParser<>), 
        typeof(MoreLikeThisResponseParser<>), 
        typeof(SpellCheckResponseParser<>), 
        typeof(StatsResponseParser<>), 
        typeof(CollapseResponseParser<>) 
    });

    container.Register<ISolrHeaderResponseParser, HeaderResponseParser<string>>();

    container.Collection.Register<IValidationRule>(new[] { 
        typeof(MappedPropertiesIsInSolrSchemaRule), 
        typeof(RequiredFieldsAreMappedRule), 
        typeof(UniqueKeyMatchesMappingRule)
    });

    container.RegisterInstance<ISolrConnection>(new SolrConnection(this.serverURL));
    container.Register(typeof(ISolrQueryResultParser<>), typeof(SolrQueryResultParser<>));
    container.Register(typeof(ISolrQueryExecuter<>), typeof(SolrQueryExecuter<>));
    container.Register(typeof(ISolrDocumentSerializer<>), typeof(SolrDocumentSerializer<>));
    container.Register(typeof(ISolrBasicOperations<>), typeof(SolrBasicServer<>));
    container.Register(typeof(ISolrBasicReadOnlyOperations<>), typeof(SolrBasicServer<>));
    container.Register(typeof(ISolrOperations<>), typeof(SolrServer<>));
    container.Register(typeof(ISolrReadOnlyOperations<>), typeof(SolrServer<>));
    container.Register<ISolrSchemaParser, SolrSchemaParser>();
    container.Register<IMappingValidator, MappingValidator>();
}
```

Comment: I have to say Steven that you answer questions way faster than any of open source project person I've ever worked with.